# I get a request denied, is there something wrong with how I'm submitting the requests?

Tags: google-maps

Here's my URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location;=41.983333,-87.766666&radius;=5000&sensor;=false&type;=doctor&name;=DPM&key;=*mykey*

I get a "request denied" response. I have activated Maps v2, Maps v3 and Places in my allowed APIs.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Start by verifying your key: https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the semicolons (i.e., ";") from your URL.  Otherwise, it will be an invalid URL as far as the API is concerned.

Comment: Thank you.   I wondered about those, but I copied the URL from the Google Places API documentation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation where the URL has the semicolons?  Thanks.